# Review a question, failed audit showing previous (skipped) question?

Tags: bug, review-audits

Seems like either I missed something, or something's broken in reviews, concerning audits. Here's a quick rundown of what just happened

- I'm reviewing ReOpen votes
- Question pops up about code I'm not familiar enough to judge (c++), it *seems* okay but I'm not sure
- I go "Skip"
- Crap question appears [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/5165673)
- I go "Leave closed"
- "STOP!" Audit failure screen pops up, showing me **the question I skipped before** [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/5165721)
- ... ?

I managed to dig up links from browser history, they're inlined in the list.

Comment: Do you still have the URL of the review you voted to leave closed? Check your browser history; it should come after the `http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/5165721` failed audit review.

Comment: Links found and added

Comment: Interesting, the crap question review was indeed still open when you failed the audit (last vote was at 12:17, you failed the audit at 12:15).